# gpg: can't open `–': No such file or directory

Tags: debian, apt

I'd like to install php 56 on my Debian Wheeyz System. So I added the dotdeb repo to apt. 
While fetching the key, an error occurred:

```
   # wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg -O- |apt-key add –
   # gpg: can't open `–': No such file or directory
```

What do I have to change to add the key to apt?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your only problem is that the dash after `apt-key add` is not the ASCII 0x2D *hyphen* character, but the Unicode U+2013 *en dash*. The former instructs `apt-key` to read the key from the standard input (where the preceding `wget` provides it through the pipe), while the latter is not treated specially, thus interpreted as a file name to read the key from. Unsurprisingly, such a file does not seem to exist in your current directory.

Comment: True: If you copy the command from the blogs, WordPress converts `-` to Unicode `–` as well.

Comment: you save my life, i just got the same problem and got the tutorial from blog like @yami

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
wget -qO - http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg | apt-key add -
```

You need a <kbd>space</kbd> after the `-O` and the character after `add` seems to be wrong. `-q` turns off the output of `wget`.